# Enable multi-file downloads from jupyterhub notebook server?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I am running [JupyterHub](https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) 0.8.2 on AWS EKS cluster.

**The question is quite simple, I want to know if it is possible to configure JupyterHub to enable multi select of files in a notebook server and download them all?**

Or, is it possible to do this with some sort of extension/modification?

My use case is that a user is exporting a lot of data, too much for one single file. There will be 100+ files.

To download the 100+ files, they will need to select each of them individually and press download. This is because the download button is disabled when you select more than 1 file

With 1 file selected:
[image]

With >1 file selected, ***Download button is gone***:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using a simple workaround which is to zip the files and download the zip file.

Example:

```
import zipfile

zf = zipfile.ZipFile('file.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
n = 100
for i in range(0, n):
    fname = f'{i}.tsv'
    print(f'Adding {fname} to zip file')
    zf.write(fname)
print('done')
```